# Electron js not displaying data from Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, electron

I am new in web development and trying to use electron js to develop an application.
I am trying to connect my electron app to mysql database running on local machine but the issue is that electron is giving insecure resource warning and not displaying the data. I tried to turn off these security features but nothing is working, I can verify that my query is fetching the data from database.

Please see the image below:

[image]

Comment: Please never include an image of some code or console output. It is really annoying.

Comment: included it just for more information

Answer (score 0):

I see a response with 3 RowDataPackage items, so it looks like turning of the security setting works.

You might want to convert the array with RowDataPackage items to an actual array by converting it to a JSON string and parse it back again.

Example:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mysqlResults))
```

Comment: Thanks, electron displays data when we turn on dev server but no data when production server is turned on.

Comment: You can access directly to RowDataPackage, just with "[index]"

Comment: @InderjitChopra what data do you get from the request at all?

Comment: And how do you connect to your database?

Comment: Its just a demo users table and connected to mysql using nodejs mysql package